# 0-manifolds are countable and discrete

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, second-countable

Want to show every 0 -manifold is a countable and discrete space.

Let M be a 0-manifold. By definition, it is second countable, Hausdorff and each point in M has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{0}$. As a homeomorphism is a bijection, every point is an open set in M. Let A $\subset$ $M$. As $A = \bigcup_{x \in A}$ $\{$ $x$ $\}$. It follows that A is open, and similarly the complement of A is open , hence A is closed. As every set is both open and closed, M is a discrete space.

How do I show that M is countable?

Answer (score 7):

Hint:

$M$ is second countable, so there is a countable base $\mathcal{U}$.  However, you have shown that every singleton $\{x\}$ is an open set.  Use the definition of base to show that $\{x\} \in \mathcal{U}$ for every $x \in M$, and conclude from this that $M$ is (at most) countable.

More generally, this shows that a second countable space can only have at most countably many isolated points.